# RewriteCond and rewriteRule to redirect depending on the domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

First of all, I've got a few domains pointing to the same webpage, each domain corresponfing to a different language. The webpage (Drupal) identifies the language using a `/lang` parameter in the url (`example.com/en`). 
I need to redirect every domain to its corresponding language so I need something like:

- example.com -> example.com/en
- example.ru -> example.ru/ru
- example.fr -> example.fr/fr

I defined some rules in htaccess but they don't do what i expected:

```
# Rewrite --- http://www.example.com => http://www.example.com/en
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en? [L,R=301]

# Rewrite --- http://www.example.ru => http://www.example.ru/ru
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /ru? [L,R=301]
```

Instead of changing `example.com` to `example.com/en` and `example.ru` to `example.ru/ru` it appends `/en` to all domains.
Is it something I am missing?

Any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: Does `/lang` always (except for `en`) match top level domain?

Comment: Yes, it's the first thing that will appear in every url just after the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
# Rewrite --- http://www.example.com => http://www.example.com/en
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/en(/(.*)$|$)
RewriteRule ^ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Rewrite --- http://www.example.ru => http://www.example.ru/ru
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^www\.example\.ru [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/ru(/(.*)$|$)
RewriteRule ^ /ru%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

You can remove `,R=301` if you want to make the rewrite invisible to the user.

Comment: Ok, i discovered that my problem was mainly due to the dns cache. Anyway I'll accept your answer since it works and provides useful information.

Comment: One thing. I've tried removing the R=301 but then it stops working. The '/lang' does not appear in the url and the cms does not change the language for the domain.

Comment: Well, the URL is expected not to change (apache will make internal redirect), but I don't why cms does not change the language (I can not test that, but on my machine I can confirm that it lands on correct `/lang/...` uri)

Comment: Also, the above RewriteCond condition should improved, from `!^/en` to `!^/en(/(.*)$|$)` (and the same for other languages). Without this, for example www.example.com/enter would be treated as correct `/en` url and there will be no redirection

Comment: Can you edit your answer then to make it more clear?

Comment: Yep, it does work but In my case I need only to force the /lang parameter if it's not already set. For example if i enter `www.mysite.com` i need to redirect to `www.mysite.com/en`. If the /lang parameter is already set what i change is the domain (as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480845/change-domain-depending-on-url-path) ).

Comment: I am aware of the other question.This edit should not break anything we set up so far, it will just be more precise and make sure some edge cases work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules :

```
RewriteEngine on
# example.com to example.com/en
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^((?!en).*)$ /en/$1 [L,R]
# example.ru|fr to example.com/ru|fr
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?.+\.(ru|fr)$
RewriteRule ^((?!ru|fr).*)$ /%1/$1 [L,R]
```

Just replace the "example.com" with "youdomain.com" in the first RewriteCondition.