# Change domain depending on url path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've got a multilingual website that works within different domains deppending on the language. All the domains share the same font code and the website (Drupal) determines the language using the path. 
Right now I've configured each domain to be redirected to its own language, so I've got:

- www.example.com -> www.example.com/en
- www.example.es  -> www.example.es/es
- www.example.ru  -> www.example.ru/ru

This way, when an user enters the website the cms will switch the language to the one corresponding to that domain.

My problem is that when someone uses the language switcher on the website, it changes all the query parameters to show the content corresponding to that language **but** does not change the domain so, if I'm in `www.example.com/en/something` and switch to spanish I will end in `www.example.com/es/algo`.

I'd need de domain to change also according to the language (which will always be written like `/en`, `/es`, `/ru` just after the domain name) and, if possible, keep the query parameters.

I've written this code in the htaccess (for russian only, as a test) but I fear It may be totally wrong since it does nothing:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/ru$1
  RewriteRule ^$1 http://www.example.ru/ru$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any advice would ve very helpful.

Comment: Where did you get the code from? it has too many syntex errors,  $1 is not allowed in cond pattern and rewrite pattern.

Comment: Yep, I fear my htaccess syntax knowledge is almost inexistent and I'm like that dog in a lab (I have not idea of what I'm doing).

Comment: dupe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37477953/rewritecond-and-rewriterule-to-redirect-depending-on-the-domain

Comment: The other question refers to a different problem even though they're related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put these before your previous rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.ru$
RewriteRule ^ru/(.*)$ http://www.example.ru%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

...
```

Be aware that this way, if for example user enters `www.example.ru/en/something`, the `/en` in path will be more important than `.ru` in hostname, thus resulting in redirect to `www.example.com/en/something`

Comment: That's exactly what I need, the /lang parameter to force a redirection to the corresponding domain, thak you very much!

Comment: One thing. It works great in all the pages but does not redirect in the homepage, do you have any idea of what can be caousing this?

Comment: I need an exact example: what do you enter in address bar, and where do you want to redirect to

Comment: www.example.es/en (without anything else) should go to www.example.com/en. Right now it whorks when there are other things after the /en/

Comment: ah, OK, that is because of slash in RewriteRule: `^en/(.)$`, remove it and you should be fine (but that way if user enters something like `www.example.en/estimate`, it could be treated as spanish because of `/es`. If that is the problem, I can try to find a workaround.

Comment: Oh, well. Since all the urls will contain the /language just after the domain It shoudln't be a problem. If you find a workaround it would be great, but, in any case, you solved my problem and I'm thankfull.

Comment: Try changing the RewriteRule pattern to `^en(/(.*)$|$)` (and for other languages accordingly)

Comment: yup, It works fine! It redirects to the right domain in the homepage and also in the pages with query parameters

Answer (score 0):

`mod_rewrite` uses regular expression. `$1` referes to a group which needs to be "defined" in the match part (using the parenthesis and the `.` as "match all" operator):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ru(.*)$ http://www.example.ru/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It works fine in the homepage, If i go to www.example.com/ru it redirects me to www.example.ru/ru, but if I'm in a different page like www.example.com/en/something it redirects me to www.example.ru//something (without the language parameter).